# What is the meaning of span here?

Tags: html, css

I am a new fresher in front end, my basics are really poor. I was reading an example code. The code is like this:

```
<ul class="list-inline intro-social-buttons">
    <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/Ferreir4Thiago" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Twitter</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://github.com/ThiagoFerreir4" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-lg "><i class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Github</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/thiagoferreir4" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">Linkedin</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.freecodecamp.com/thiagoferreira" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-fire fa-fw"></i> <span class="network-name">freeCodeCamp</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

After I checked whether there is a class called `network-name`, the answer is no. So I want to know what is the meaning of `span class="network-name"` here?

Comment: try removing it and seeing what difference it makes (or if it makes a difference)

Comment: What do you mean by _"After I check whether there is a class called network-name,the answer is no"_? How are you checking?

Comment: @David Thomas By check the css code

Comment: @郭佳乐 `class` attributes aren't exclusively used by CSS. JavaScript may target elements by class name as well.

Comment: @Noam Hacker By checking the css code,and there is no class called network-name

Comment: @gfullam there is no js code

Comment: Sometimes classes are added to markup to provide the front end developer with flexibility. As the front end dev, you may find it useful to have that `class` so that you can target those elements with CSS or JS. The purpose of `class` here is really only known by the creator of the markup. We can only speculate. But it is apparent that the `span` was added to apply the `class` to the wrapped text.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Your code example appears to come from https://github.com/jcutrell/bootstrap-tour-tutorial/blob/master/index.html which includes a CSS file https://github.com/jcutrell/bootstrap-tour-tutorial/blob/master/css/landing-page.css that *does* select elements with the class `network-name` and *does* include JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Span has [no meaning](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element). It is a generic inline element with no associated semantics.

> I check whether there is a class called network-name,the answer is no.

The answer is "yes". There is an HTML element with `network-name` in the class attribute. That makes the element a member of that class.

There might not be any CSS that makes use of it. There might not be any JS that makes use of it. The class does exist though.

Comment: But whether in the css code or js code,there is no class defination about `network-name`?

Comment: @郭佳乐 — And all that means is that no CSS or JS makes use of it.

Comment: This answer, while technically correct, is only going to confuse a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

`span` is generally used for applying many attributes to inline content. Alone it adds no value at all to the page. If there is no JavaScript, CSS or other code using this class `network-name` or targeting the `span` element directly then it will make no difference if these `span` are removed.

See the [HTML span tag W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span).

Comment: `class` attributes aren't exclusively used by CSS. JavaScript may target elements by class name as well. Removing the class could have unintended consequences.

Comment: "See the HTML span tag W3C documentation." — You've linked to W3Schools. W3Schools is not the W3C, is not affiliated with the W3C and is, while no longer horrifically awful, not very good.

Comment: The OP has revealed there is no JS, so this is the most clear answer.

Comment: @Quentin I updated, sorry for the mistake. My goal was definitely not to cite W3Schools even if the information they provide regarding `span` elements is not detailed but still correct.

Comment: Whatever their problems may or may not be these days, W3Schools is better resource for beginners than W3C -- controversial but true. The W3C documentation is generally dry, badly written, and completely unhelpful for beginners (although the Wiki you linked to is better).

Comment: For anyone who is going to complain about W3Schools, it's worth noting that even W3Fools states: "For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience." There's no problem with pushing beginners in their direction these days... provided they branch out to other resources, too.

Answer (score -3):

The span tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.

The span tag provides no visual change by itself.

The span tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.

The  tag also occupies only the space it needs to display what it contains

check [W3Schools Span Definition and usage](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)

As for the class="network-name" check the head of the document where you got the code its surely linked to some online style sheet(most likely Bootstrap)